# Select everything except comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I know how to remove comments from text but i'm looking for something different.

I want to select everything except the code block.

I used following regex:

```
/^(?!(\/\*([\s\S]+)\*\/)).*/gm
```

You can check it here: https://regex101.com/r/cN5aT1/2

But it is not working with multiline comments ...

Comment: **I don't want to select comments** ... I want everything else other than comments ! .. Thank you

Comment: Can the comments be anywhere, for instance also in the middle of a line?

Comment: @torazaburo: you don't know where this code is used. To downvote also provide reasons (this is not JS is CSS) or valid counterexamples (they are welcomed).

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to `replace` the comments from text with `\/\*.*?\*\/` instead.

Though if you do want it and assuming that this will not go into your production code you can try

```
/([^*\/][^*\/][^*\/]*)(?=\/\*.*?\*\/|$)/gs
```

https://regex101.com/r/cN5aT1/6

Comment: It does not select text after the last comment.

Comment: JS does not support `/s` dotall modifier. Also, for long multiline comments, this regex will work very slowly or might even freeze the app due to lazy dot matching subpattern.

Comment: @lex82 fixed. thanks.. @stribizhev To fix that we can use [\s\S] instead of `.` Though as I have already mentioned, its more logical to replace..Both in terms of performance and bug

Comment: @bobblebubble: the code is css, so the failling case it's more like [this](https://regex101.com/r/cN5aT1/8)

Answer (score 1):

**Strip out comments**

Remove every css comments (in or extra block and with stars `*` inside) using the `replace` function with the following regex:

```
/\s*[/][*](?:[^*]|[*][^/])*[*][/][ \t]*/g
```

**Regex Breakout**  <kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sN0lT4/2)</kbd>

```
/                  # Regex start delimiter
\s*                # select any whitespace char (including the newlines preceding the comment)
[/][*]             # match comment start delimiter '/*'
(?:[^*]|[*][^/])*  # select zero or more not star ('*') chars (also newlines) 
                   # or a star and the following char (that is not '/')
[*][/]             # match comment stop delimiter '*/'
[ \t]*             # match any space or tabs (no newlines to preserve indentations)
/g                 # Regex close delimiter and global flag
```

*About performance*: The code below is **14 times faster** than the code proposed in the other answer with the lazy modifier:

- [Not lazy - 920 steps](https://regex101.com/r/sN0lT4/4) vs [Lazy - 12927 steps](https://regex101.com/r/cN5aT1/4)

**Live Js Demo**

```js
var filter = /\s*[/][*](?:[^*]|[*][^/])*[*][/][ \t]*/g; 
var input  = '.class-n {\n\n}\n\n/* Select everything but these comments */\n\n.class-1 {\n    font-family: \'SourceCodePro\';\n    font-size: 16px; /* a comment with\n **stars***** */\n    line-height: 18px;\n}\n\n/* Select everything but these comments */\n\n.class-2 {\n    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40); /* another\n    inline comments that\nspans on multiple lines */\n    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);\n    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;\n}\n\n/* Single line */\n\n/* Multiline\n   Comment */\n';

var output = input.replace(filter,'');

document.getElementById('input').innerHTML  += '<xmp>' + input + '</xmp>';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<xmp>' + output + '</xmp>';
```

```css
.flexbox-container {
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.flexbox-container > div {
 width: 50%;
 padding: 15px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.flexbox-container > div:first-child {
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
   <div id="input"><h3>Original Css</h3></div>
   <div id="output"><h3>Stripped Css</h3></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very quick and easy solution to get text that should not be matched with a specific pattern is using `String#split()`.

So, [the best regex to match `/* */` comments](https://regex101.com/r/gN8uY8/1) I know is

```
/\/\*[^*]*\*+([^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//g
```

Then, just split the input with the regex:

```js
var re = /\/\*[^*]*\*+([^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//g; 
var s = '.class-n {\n\n}\n\n/* I want to select everything but these comments */\n\n.class-1 {\n    font-family: \'SourceCodePro\'; \n    font-size: 16px;\n    line-height: 18px;\n}\n\n/* I want to select everything but these comments */\n\n.class-2 {\n    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);\n    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);\n    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;\n}\n\n/* Single line */\n\n/* Multiline\n   Comment */\n\nSome text here';
var res = s.split(re).filter(Boolean);
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4)+"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting comments in JavaScript isn't a trivial solution, you cannot rely on RegEx alone for that. Only a proper parser, like [Esprima](https://github.com/jquery/esprima), can do that correctly.

The easiest way for you is to use the code/content with all its comments removed.

For that you can use library [decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment). It guarantees correct comments removal, as it relies on [Esprima](https://github.com/jquery/esprima) to identify all the regular expressions:

```
var decomment = require('decomment');

var code = "var t; // comments";

decomment(code); //=> var t;
```

For build systems / task runners see [gulp-decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/gulp-decomment) and [grunt-decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/grunt-decomment).